# JqGrid suporta formatação com quebra de linha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, asp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde uso **Jquery(1.11)** com **JqGrid(4.54)**. Essa aplicação ja foi desenvolvida em ***ASP***, onde em seu conteúdo há um totalizador de dados por login junto com os dados exibidos como resultado na tabela. Não sei se no **JqGrid** teria como aplicar essa quebra de linha para exibir os totais. Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível ou alguma outra maneira de exibir esses totais usando JqGrid?

Segue abaixo a tabela do código em ASP:

[image: Tabela em ASP]

Logo a tabela usando o JqGrid:

[image: Tabela JqGrid]

e aqui o código do Grid:

```
     var modeloColunas = [
            { name : "login", index : "login", label: "Login", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "login" },
            { name : "nome", index : "nome", label: "Nome", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "nome" },             
            { name : "canal", index : "canal", label: "Canal", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "canal" },
            { name : "tipoSolicitacao", index : "tipoSolicitacao", label: "Tipo Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "tipoSolicitacao" },
            { name : "totalAnalise", index : "totalAnalise", label: "Total Analise", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", jsonmap: "totalAnalise" },
            { name : "totalAtendimento", index : "totalAtendimento", label: "Total Atendimento", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "totalAtendimento" },           
            { name : "mediaAtendimento", index : "mediaAtendimento", label: "M&eacute;dia Atendimento", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", jsonmap: "mediaAtendimento" }];

          var subGridHabilitado = true;

        // We pass two parameters: subgrid_id is an id of the div tag created within a        table. The row_id is the id of the row.
        // If we want to pass additional parameters to the url we can use the method getRowData(row_id) - which returns associative array in type
        // name-value here we can easy construct the following.
        var gridInterno = function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var rowData = $("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid("getRowData", row_id);
            var urlParametrosFormularioInterno = "?" + $("form .filtroRelatorioInterno").fieldSerialize() + "&filtro.tipoSolicitacao=" + retornaValorTipoSolicitacao(rowData.tipoSolicitacao) + "&filtro.login=" + rowData.login;
            var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
            var idPaginacao = "#paginacaoSub" + row_id;
            $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id=\"" + subgrid_table_id + "\" class=\"scroll\"></table><div id=\"paginacaoSub" + row_id + "\"></div>");
            $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                url: urlRelatorioInterno + urlParametrosFormularioInterno,
                colModel: [
                    { name: "solicitacao", index: "solicitacao", jsonmap: "solicitacao", label: "Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o", sortable: true, sorttype: "int" },
                    { name: "dataInicioAnalise", index: "dataInicioAnalise", jsonmap: "dataInicioAnalise", label: "Data In&iacute;cio da An&aacute;lise", sortable: true, sorttype: "dataInicioAnalise", formatter: "date" },
                    { name: "dataFinalAnalise", index: "dataFinalAnalise", jsonmap: "dataFinalAnalise", label: "Data Final da An&aacute;lise", sortable: true, sorttype: "date", formatter: "date"  },
                    { name: "tipoAnalise", index: "tipoAnalise", jsonmap: "tipoAnalise", label: "Tipo An&aacute;lise", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: "tempoAnalise", index: "tempoAnalise", jsonmap: "tempoAnalise", label: "Tempo An&aacute;lise", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
                    { name: "fila", index: "fila", jsonmap: "fila", label: "Fila", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" }],
                pager: idPaginacao,
                width: 1073,
                height: "auto",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                loadonce: true,
                beforeRequest: function() { $.blockUI(); },
                gridComplete: function() { $.unblockUI(); }
            }).jqGrid("navGrid", idPaginacao, { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false
            }).jqGrid("navButtonAdd", idPaginacao, {
                caption: "Exportar Excel",
                onClickButton: function() {
                    $.blockUI();
                    $("#botaoExportarXLS").downloadArquivo(urlExportarExcelInterno, urlParametrosFormularioInterno.substring(1));
                },
                id: "botaoExportarXLS"
            }).jqGrid("navButtonAdd", idPaginacao, {
                caption: "Exportar PDF",
                onClickButton: function() {
                    $.blockUI();
                    $("#botaoExportarPDF").downloadArquivo(urlExportarPdfInterno, urlParametrosFormularioInterno.substring(1));
                },
                id: "botaoExportarPDF"
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta você inserir `<br/>` no texto que você quer quebrar em linhas. Seja no servidor, antes de enviar, seja no cliente, antes de popular o grid (eu não encontrei no seu código o momento em que você popula, então não posso dar uma instrução mais específica). Aqui está [um exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/2n8w6/) que confirma que esse método funciona. Repare nas quebras de linha inseridas dentro das strings a serem exibidas:

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "0220<br/>0220", "OPEN"], 
            [48769, "APPR", "", "7773<br/>3337", "ENTERED"]];
```